# How do I find the theta notation for this block?

Tags: algorithm, math, notation, big-o

The block is:

```
    i=2  
    while(i<n){  
        i=i*i;  
        x=x+1;  
    }
```

I need to find the theta notation for how many times x=x+1 executes. I created a table with some sample values but I can't figure out how to move on from there.  Here are my sample values:

```
(n) - (# times looped)  
  3 - 1  
  5 - 2  
 20 - 3  
400 - 4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to think about this is to trace through the values of i in your loop.  Before the first iteration, the value is 2 = 2<sup>1</sup>.  After the second iteration, it's 4 = 2<sup>2</sup>.  After the third iteration, it's 16 = 2<sup>4</sup>.  After the fourth iteration, it's 256 = 2<sup>8</sup>.  After the fifth, it's 65,536 = 2<sup>16</sup>.

As you can see, after k iterations of the loop, the value of i is 2<sup>2<sup>k</sup></sup>.  This means that the number of iterations will (roughly) correspond to the lowest value of k such that

> 2<sup>2<sup>k</sup></sup> ≥ n

Taking the logarithm of both sides twice, we get

> 2<sup>2<sup>k</sup></sup> ≥ n
>
> 2<sup>k</sup> ≥ log<sub>2</sub> n
>
> k ≥ log<sub>2</sub> log<sub>2</sub> n

So the number of loop iterations is roughly log<sub>2</sub> log<sub>2</sub> n.  Accordingly, the loop runs O(log log n) times.  More precisely, the loop runs Θ(log log n) times, since the loop will not stop until k iterations have elapsed.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh wow I didn't think of that.  I was trying so hard to get an equation similar to the ones in the textbook examples in a way that it would fit.  Thanks.